# Notifications unexpanded text

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

How do I put a text (view the image below) in the notification when it's unexpanded?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Notification.Builder#setContentText(CharSequence text)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentText(java.lang.CharSequence))

Set the **second line of text** in the platform notification template.

Also see [Anatomy of a Notification](https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-anatomy-of-a-notification). For how to build one, see [Building a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)